# Unobvious error in python-sfml short example

Tags: python, sfml

Getting started with python-sfml. This code

```
import sfml

window = sfml.RenderWindow(sfml.VideoMode(640, 480), "FooBar")

try:
    texture = sfml.Texture.from_file("brick_002.jpg")
    sprite = sfml.Sprite(texture)

    font = sfml.Font.from_file("arial.ttf")
    text = sfml.Text("Math Rocks!")


except IOError:
    exit(1)

while window.is_open:
    for event in window.events:
        if type(event) is sfml.CloseEvent:
        window.close()

    window.clear()
    window.draw(sprite)
    window.draw(text)
    window.display()
```

and getting this mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfml.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sfml
  File "/home/montreal/projects/foo/sfml/sfml.py", line 4, in <module>
    window = sfml.RenderWindow(sfml.VideoMode(640, 480), "FooBar")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RenderWindow'
```

But in interpreter everyting works fine (I can create window, add texture and close it). What can be wrong?

Comment: You named your script `sfml.py` and this confuses the import statement: the script will import itself, then on line 4 will try to look for a `RenderWindow` inside itself.

Comment: Don't feel bad, it's surprisingly common!

Comment: I've renamed my file but still getting this error. And somewhy interpreter uses old version of the file.

Comment: you need to close the Python interpreter, or type: `sfml=reload(sfml)`

Comment: (In python 3, first you need to `from imp import reload` )

Comment: Thank you, it is finally working :)